# NSIS Error creating shortcut on desktop

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm trying to use NSIS for installing my application.
When trying to create shortcut on the desktop, it fails.
this is the script relevant part i'm using:

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File "${BIN_DIRECTORY}\app.exe"
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\app\app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe"
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\app.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe"
```

This is the log:

```
Extract: app.exe... 100%
Create shortcut: C:\Users\roeia\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\app\app.lnk
Error creating shortcut: E:\Users\roeia\Desktop\app.lnk
```

the path is correct, and i don't have any problem to create or modify files there.
I'm using windows 7 64bit.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a right problem: do you run the installer as admin?

Specifying `RequestExecutionLevel` in the script may help to do so:

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;try also with 'highest'
```

Comment: Trying admin/highest made no difference, still getting the errors.  

The default location of setup is on server, tried running it locally but the same results.

Comment: Why is admin level required to create a link on the user's desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the use of \r in the executeable path is causing the problem. Try \r to avaoid character substitution.